# mipmap и drawable - в каких случаях использовать

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

Здравствуйте!
 
В проекте, над которым сейчас работаю, ВСЕ изображения были помещены предыдущим разработчиком в mipmap-xxxx. В drawable остались только .xml файлы.
Мне казалось, что mipmap должны использоваться только для иконок приложения.
Собственно вопрос - на сколько правильно хранить ВСЕ изображения в mipmap или же это ошибка? Было бы хорошо, по возможности, использовать в ответах ссылки на документацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правильно написали, что mipmap обычно используется для иконок приложения. `mipmap` появились в android 4.3 [Mipmapping for drawables](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#MipMap). 
В данном [статье](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) описано почему лучше для иконок использовать `mipmap`. 
Если кратко, то когда ваши иконки расположены в `drawable - [разрешение]`, то могут возникнуть проблемы отображения иконки не того размера.